# expl3 — fully expand before \use:c

Tags: expl3, latex3

Consider

```
\def\niii{10}
\def\niiii{21}
```

I can easily obtain it via

```tex
\use:c {niii} % 10
\use:c {niiii} % 21
```

However I would like to create csname dynamically using `\int_step_inline:nn {4} {i}`. I tried the following, but neither worked

```
\use:c { n\int_step_inline:nn {4} {i} }
\exp_args:Nx \use:c { n\int_step_inline:nn {4} {i} }

\tl_set:Nx \l_tempa_tl { n\int_step_inline:nn {4}{i} }
\use:c {\tl_use:N \l_tempa_tl}
```

Comment: `c` arguments are always fully expanded, but `\int_step_inline:nn`  is not expandable (no * in interface3 description)

Comment: `\use:c { n\prg_replicate:nn {4} {i} }` should work.

Comment: In OpTeX, there is no problem: `\def\niiii{21}` followed by `\cs{n\fornum 1..4\do{i}}` expands to `21`.

Comment: @wipet yes same as latex, there is no problem if you use an expandable loop and it fails if you use a non-expandable one.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The argument to `\use:c` must expand to character tokens only. Since `\int_step_inline:nn` is not fully expandable (no asterisk or hollow star next to it in the manual), it cannot be used in such a place.

You *could* use `\int_step_function:nN` like

```
\cs_new:Nn \__antshar_makei:n { i }

\use:c { note \int_step_function:nN { 3 } \__antshar_makei:n }
```

but if the purpose is to obtain a string of four `i`'s, it's much simpler to use `\prg_replicate:nn`

```
\use:c { note \prg_replicate:nn { 3 } { i } }
```

But probably you *don't* want to create `\notei`, `\noteii`, `\noteiii` and so on. You can define a numeric array using

```
\intarray_new:Nn \g_antshar_note_intarray {100}
```

This allocates an array of length 100. If you want to store values in the array (which is initialized to all 0 entries)

```
\intarray_gset:Nnn \g_antshar_note_intarray { 3 } { 10 }
\intarray_gset:Nnn \g_antshar_note_intarray { 4 } { 21 }
```

and you can (expandably) retrieve a value with

```
\intarray_item:Nn \g_antshar_note_intarray { 3 }
```

Comment: doesn't that last one generate just 3 i's?

Comment: @daleif I used 3, but 4 would be good as well. I like better 3 than 4. ;-)

Answer (score 2):

The command `\int_to_roman:n` can be used inside `\use:c`.

[image]

```
\documentclass[border=6pt,varwidth]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\def\niii{10}
\def\nxxiv{21}
\use:c { n \int_to_roman:n { 3 } }\\
\use:c { n \int_to_roman:n { 24 } }
\ExplSyntaxOff
\end{document}
```